# interop.excel does not work on iis7.5 - Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472

Tags: iis-7.5, excel-interop

I have a web application in c# in VS2010, that uses Microsoft.Interop.Excel 12 to export data to an Excel Spreadsheet.
The application works well on Windows Server 2003, and also on Windows Server 2008 R2 in debug mode from VS2010.
When I run the application on iis7.5, I get Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472.
I have used dcomcnfg to give permissions to the appPool identity user on Microsoft Excel Application,
and created Desktop folder in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile and in C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile, with permissions to the same user.
The server I'm using is Virtual Windows Server 2008 R2 (on top of Windows Server 2012).
Can anyone help ?
Thanks a lot